# Is it possible to retrieve the status of the Unified Write Filter in Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-10, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently working with Asp.Net Core MVC on Windows 10 Enterprise and I need to know in my code if the Unified Write filter (UWF) is on or off and consequently put it on a web page to let the user know.
Is it possible?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this is to run the uwfmgr application "uwfmgr get-config" and redirect standard output. Then you can search for Filter state: ON|OFF in the resulting output. Apparently there is no API for the write filter?

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to share a snip of that code?  I've been trying to redirect uwfmgr to standard output like I do with many other things like ipconfig, netsh, ect but uwfmgr seems to be encoded differently or something as the output is unreadable.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I realize this is a belated answer. Yeah - the problem is that uwfmgr outputs in UTF-16. The following is an example of how to convert from this to UTF-8.
`byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultMessage);
string convertedOutput = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteArray);
const string filterStateOnSearchString = "Filter state:    ON";

return convertedOutput.Contains(filterStateOnSearchString);`